# @tusharghoshbd ngx-datatable not displaying related data

Tags: angular

I am implementing @tusharghoshbd ngx-datatable to display data in Angular-12

I have this API JSON GET Request as shown below:

```
{
  "message": "You have successfully Retrieved User Detail",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
    "user": {
      "id": 2,
      "department_id": 2,
      "first_name": "Frank",
      "active": "1",
      "last_name": "Akram",
      "roles": [{
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Manager",
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Supervisor"
        }
      ],
      "department": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Account",
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Component:

```
export class SiteInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('actionTpl', {
    static: true
  }) actionTpl: TemplateRef < any > ;
  @ViewChild('addressTpl', {
    static: true
  }) addressTpl: TemplateRef < any > ;

  isLoading: boolean = false;
  options: any = {};
  userInfoList: any[] = [];
  columns: any = {};


  constructor(private userInfoService: SUserInfoService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.userInfoService.getAllUserDetail().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.userInfoList = data.results.users;
        console.log(data);
      },
      error => {
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    );

    this.options = {
      loader: true
    };
    this.columns = [{
        key: 'id',
        title: '<div class="blue"> ID</div>',
        width: 60,
        sorting: true,
        align: {
          head: 'center',
          body: 'center'
        },
        vAlign: {
          head: 'bottom',
          body: 'middle'
        }
      },
      {
        key: 'first_name',
        title: '<div class="blue">First Name</div>',
        width: 100
      },
      {
        key: 'last_name',
        title: '<div class="blue">Last Name</div>',
        width: 100
      },
      {
        key: 'department.name',
        title: '<div class="blue">Department</div>',
        align: {
          head: 'left'
        },
        width: 100,
        sorting: true
      },
      {
        key: 'roles.name',
        title: '<div class="blue">Roles</div>',
        align: {
          head: 'left'
        },
        width: 100,
        sorting: true
      },
      {
        key: 'active',
        title: '<div class="blue">Active</div>',
        align: {
          head: 'left'
        },
        width: 100,
        sorting: true
      },
      {
        key: '',
        title: '<div class="blue">Action</div>',
        align: {
          head: 'center',
          body: 'center'
        },
        sorting: false,
        width: 80,
        cellTemplate: this.actionTpl
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ngx-datatable tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" [data]="userInfoList" [columns]="columns" [options]="options">
  <ngx-caption>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-6 ">
        <b>
                  <i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  Site Info. List
              </b>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ngx-caption>

  <ng-template #addressTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">

  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #actionTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">

  </ng-template>

</ngx-datatable>
```

I was able to display every other data that are that relationships (foreign key): first_name, last_name etc. But I have two issues:

1. When I did roles.name and department.name nothing is being display
2. For active 1 = True and 0 = False.

Since there is no way to do it from HTML IN @tusharghoshbd, unlike plain table td, tr. I checked the manual for @tusharghoshbd but no luck.

How do I resolve these two (2) issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue & Concern

Would like to raise up that you are accessing `data.results.users` which is **NOT VALID** for your JSON result.

```js
this.userInfoList = data.results.users;
```

```
{
  "message": "You have successfully Retrieved User Detail",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
    "user": {
      ...
    },
  }
}
```

Meanwhile, since your JSON **returns a single object but not array**.

### Solution for Issue: Cast single object to array

> site-info.component.ts

```js
this.userInfoList = [data.results.user];
```

---

### Solution for Question

To display the department name and name for each role, you can use `cellTemplate`.
To customize the displayed value of Active, you also use `cellTemplate` with pipe.

> to-boolean.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'toBoolean'
})
export class ToBooleanPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): string {
    switch (value) {
      case true:
      case 'true':
      case 1:
      case '1':
        return "True";
      default:
        return "False";
    }
  }
}
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { ToBooleanPipe } from './pipes/to-boolean.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ ... ],
  declarations: [ ..., ToBooleanPipe ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> site-info.component.html

```
<ngx-datatable tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" [data]="userInfoList" [columns]="columns"
  [options]="options">
  ...

  <ng-template #activeTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">
    {{columnValue | toBoolean}}
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #departmentTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">
    {{columnValue.name}}
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #rolesTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">
    <ng-template ngFor let-obj [ngForOf]="columnValue">
      {{ obj.name }}
      <br />
    </ng-template>
  </ng-template>

</ngx-datatable>
```

> site-info.component.ts

```
export class SiteInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  @ViewChild('activeTpl', {
    static: true
  })
  activeTpl: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('departmentTpl', {
    static: true
  })
  departmentTpl: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('rolesTpl', {
    static: true
  })
  rolesTpl: TemplateRef<any>;

  ...

  ngOnInit(): void {
    ...

    this.columns = [
      ...
      {
        key: 'department',
        title: '<div class="blue">Department</div>',
        align: {
          head: 'left'
        },
        width: 100,
        sorting: true,
        cellTemplate: this.departmentTpl
      },
      {
        key: 'roles',
        title: '<div class="blue">Roles</div>',
        align: {
          head: 'left'
        },
        width: 100,
        sorting: true,
        cellTemplate: this.rolesTpl
      },
      {
        key: 'active',
        title: '<div class="blue">Active</div>',
        align: {
          head: 'left'
        },
        width: 100,
        sorting: true,
        cellTemplate: this.activeTpl
      },
      ...
    ];

    this.userInfoService.getAllUserDetail().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.userInfoList = [data.results.user];
        console.log(data);
      },
      error => {
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sts2eq)

Comment: Hi @user11352561, I would recommend that you have to create a new question for your new requirement. As my answer aimed to solve your current question. Anyway, don't hesitate to ask new question. You may upvote/mark my solution as the correct answer if it helps you. Thank you.

Comment: How do I make the color Green if True and Red if False at the HTML. Thanks