# Angular - How to customize id as autoincrement in @tusharghoshbd ngx-datatable

Tags: angular

I have this code for @tushargho

```js
export class SiteInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('actionTpl', {
    static: true
  })
  actionTpl: TemplateRef < any > ;
  @ViewChild('addressTpl', {
    static: true
  })
  addressTpl: TemplateRef < any > ;
  @ViewChild('activeTpl', {
    static: true
  })
  activeTpl: TemplateRef < any > ;
  @ViewChild('departmentTpl', {
    static: true
  })

  isLoading: boolean = false;
  options: any = {};
  userInfoList: any[] = [];
  columns: any = {};

  constructor(private userInfoService: UserInfoService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.options = {
      loader: true
    };
    this.columns = [{
        key: 'id',
        title: '<div class="blue"> ID</div>',
        width: 60,
        sorting: true,
        align: {
          head: 'center',
          body: 'center'
        },
        vAlign: {
          head: 'bottom',
          body: 'middle'
        }
      },
      {
        key: 'first_name',
        title: '<div class="blue">First Name</div>',
        width: 100
      },
      {
        key: 'last_name',
        title: '<div class="blue">Last Name</div>',
        width: 100
      },
      {
        key: 'department',
        title: '<div class="blue">Department</div>',
        align: {
          head: 'left'
        },
        width: 100,
        sorting: true,
        cellTemplate: this.departmentTpl
      },
      {
        key: '',
        title: '<div class="blue">Action</div>',
        align: {
          head: 'center',
          body: 'center'
        },
        sorting: false,
        width: 80,
        cellTemplate: this.actionTpl
      }
    ];

    this.isLoading = true;
    this.userInfoService.getAllUserDetail().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.userInfoList = [data.results.user];

        this.options = {
          ...this.options,
          loader: false
        };
      },
      error => {
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<ngx-datatable tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" [data]="userInfoList" [columns]="columns" [options]="options">
  <ngx-caption>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-6 ">
        <b>
                  <i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  Site Info. List
              </b>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ngx-caption>

  <ng-template #addressTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">

  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #actionTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">

  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #departmentTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">
    {{columnValue.name}}
  </ng-template>

</ngx-datatable>
```

In @tusharghoshbd ngx-datatable, how do I format key: 'id', as autoincrement instead of taking the value from the DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the ID column with auto increment with `cellTemplate`.

**Assumption**: The JSON data is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68550158/8017690).

> site-info.component.html

```
<ngx-datatable tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" [data]="userInfoList" [columns]="columns"
  [options]="options">
  ...

  <ng-template #idTpl let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-row="row">
    {{rowIndex+1}}
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable>
```

> site-info.component.ts

```js
export class SiteInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  @ViewChild('idTpl', {
    static: true
  })
  idTpl: TemplateRef<any>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    ...

    this.columns = [
      {
        key: 'id',
        title: '<div class="blue"> ID</div>',
        width: 60,
        sorting: true,
        align: {
          head: 'center',
          body: 'center'
        },
        vAlign: {
          head: 'bottom',
          body: 'middle'
        },
        cellTemplate: this.idTpl
      },
      ...
    ];
  }
}
```

[Sample solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2zegx6)

---

### Remarks:

If you just want to display the row index for each record, you may go for it this way.

However, I will not recommend that you use this row index for performing data insertion/update/retrieve/delete **(C.R.U.D)** to DB. As IDs are unique and suppose it should be auto-increment by the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ngx-datatable-column name="S No.">
      <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-row="row">
         {{rowIndex+1}}
     </ng-template>
 </ngx-datatable-column>
```

Comment: It doesn't work in @tusharghoshbd ngx-datatable. I have tried it.